# Django : about an optimized grouping with a QuerySet

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I have a model like so :

```
class ConsumptionTracking(Model):
        cat = models.ForeignKey('Cat', null=True, db_index=True, blank=True)
        time = models.TimeField(null=False, blank=False)
        date = models.DateField(null=False, db_index=True, blank=False)
        water_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        food_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to retrieve all objects from a certain date, and having them grouped by date eg.:

```
{"01-02-2016": [ConsumptionTracking<1>, ConsumptionTracking<2>], 
"02-02-2016": [ConsumptionTracking<3>, ConsumptionTracking<x>, ConsumptionTracking<x+1>]}
```

Having thousands of entries, the only way i've found to do it using set and a for loop takes approximatively 2 seconds, which is too much :

```
model = ConsumptionTracking
user = request.user
data = set(i for i in model.objects.filter(cat=cat, cat__owner=user, date__gte=date_from))
date_set = set([str(o.date) for o in data])
aggregated = dict([(d, []) for d in date_set])
for d in date_set:
    for o in data:
        if str(o.date) == d:
            aggregated[d].append(ConsumptionTrackingSerializer(o).data)
```

Can I do that at the QuerySet level? Can I do better to go faster?

Thanks.

Comment: You could have at least posted your real model. Your query and model are poles apart

Comment: Edited, sorry about that.

Comment: So how do you want the other columns aggregated. I suppose water_amount and food_amount can be summed but what of time and cat?

Comment: I just want something like a dict of objects, grouped by day as in the example. Then the aggregation 'itself' is done client side, displayed in a chart.
The way i'm doing it atm is too performance cutting.

Comment: First there's no need to aggregate at **both** the database and in your code. However when you are aggregating you either have to leave out some columns or decide how to aggregate on them. I will add an answer soon that will hopefully explain things. (or someone will beat me to it)

Comment: Sure, tough the 'aggregate' term is a bit confusing for me. I would like the database to do this grouping work, as the code doing it takes too long. This endpoint is used by a mobile app, retrieving data and displaying in a chart.